# Unable to Use Nuget with MvvmCross - PCL

Tags: nuget, mvvmcross, printer-control-language

Following the tutorial for mvvmcross here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DHDMNB_IeY&list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W&index=1

I've set up my PCL xml files to include MonoTouch and Mono for Android as instructed here: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html

If I try to use nuget I get an error that an item with the same key has already been added:
[image: screenshot]

I can add other project types to the solution and NuGet works fine, it's something specific to PCL projects.  Here is the console output:

```
PM> Install-Package MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore (≥ 3.0.8.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport (≥ 3.0.8.1)'.
Installing 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.8.1'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.8.1'.
Installing 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.8.1'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.8.1'.
Installing 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack 3.0.8.1'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack 3.0.8.1'.
Adding 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.8.1' to BLUBCNMOBL.Core.
Uninstalling 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.8.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.8.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : An item with the same key has already been added.
At line:1 char:1
```

Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012 (Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2)
Nuget v 2.5

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that one of the XML files you added git snafu'd during copy and paste.

Try deleting whatever you added and try adding them again.

---

Alternatively, it could be that someone else has added conflicting files? Eg xamarin have recently added pcl support so maybe they've added files?

---

To try collecting more info, you could try using the nuget command line - does that give you any more diagnostic info.

Comment: I've added the output from nuget command line to the question.  Will try removing, re-adding the files.

Comment: I deleted the files, then verified they didn't show up as options for PCL.  I then went to the xml files you have posted, clicked view raw, and then save from there (so no copy and paste).  I'm still running into the same problem.  To get past it for now I will try manual download of the binaries, but that doesn't solve this annoying problem.  Thanks :)

Comment: did you ever get this fixed? I am having the same problem.

Comment: nope, still have the same problem and regularly have to download binaries.. nuget rendered useless